# The data could not be converted

Tags: docusignapi

I had a working function call the Docusign SOAP API and now all of the sudden its not working. I get the error "The data could not be converted" when I call the CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms method. Here is my code.

```
Dim _userName As String = ""

Dim _apiUrl As String = "https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx"

Dim _accountId As String = "d90f6802-fa06-42b4-ac3b-5959c3905002"

Dim _password As String = "WWWxyz123"

Dim _email As String = "JGarland@etgroup.net"

Dim _integratorKey As String = "ETGX-1f61c95b-06bd-400b-9604-f247fda0238c"

Sub Main()

    'GetSignatureSpot(Nothing)
    'GetPDF()
    'GetCertificate()
    'Exit Sub

    _userName = "[" + _integratorKey + "]"
    _userName = _userName & _email

    Dim _apiClient As DocuSign.DSAPIServiceSoapClient = New DocuSign.DSAPIServiceSoapClient("DSAPIServiceSoap", _apiUrl)

    _apiClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _userName

    _apiClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _password

    Dim envelopeInfo As DocuSign.EnvelopeInformation = New DocuSign.EnvelopeInformation()

    envelopeInfo.AccountId = _accountId

    envelopeInfo.EmailBlurb = "Please Sign Your Loan Documents"

    envelopeInfo.Subject = "Please Sign Your Loan Documents"

    'Recipients
    Dim recipient1 As DocuSign.Recipient = New DocuSign.Recipient()

    recipient1.UserName = "John Doe"
    recipient1.Email = "Support@etgroup.net"
    recipient1.Type = DocuSign.RecipientTypeCode.Signer
    recipient1.RoutingOrder = 1
    recipient1.RoutingOrderSpecified = True
    recipient1.RoleName = "Borrower 1"
    recipient1.ID = "1"

    Dim recipient2 As DocuSign.Recipient = New DocuSign.Recipient()

    recipient2.UserName = "Jane Doe"
    recipient2.Email = "JGarland@etgroup.net"
    recipient2.Type = DocuSign.RecipientTypeCode.Signer
    recipient2.RoutingOrder = 2
    recipient2.RoutingOrderSpecified = True
    recipient2.RoleName = "Borrower 2"
    recipient2.ID = "2"

    Dim signers(1) As DocuSign.Recipient

    signers(0) = recipient1
    signers(1) = recipient2

    'Create draft with all the composite template information
    Dim status As DocuSign.EnvelopeStatus
    Dim compositTemplate(1) As DocuSign.CompositeTemplate

    Dim template As DocuSign.CompositeTemplate
    Dim template2 As DocuSign.CompositeTemplate

    'Template 1
    template = CreateTemplate(1, "Attorney Selection Notice", "F364E20C-D0E6-4735-89E2-8891424BA364", signers, "AttorneySelection.pdf")

    compositTemplate(0) = template

    'Template 2
    template2 = CreateTemplate(2, "Notice of No Oral", "F5A536C3-81AB-4C32-B56A-9F764624C3C4", signers, "NoticeOral.pdf")

    compositTemplate(1) = template2

    status = _apiClient.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms(envelopeInfo, compositTemplate, True)

End Sub

Private Function CreateTemplate(sequence As Integer, templateName As String, templateID As String, signers() As DocuSign.Recipient, docPath As String) As DocuSign.CompositeTemplate

    Dim template As DocuSign.CompositeTemplate = New DocuSign.CompositeTemplate()

    'Server Template
    Dim serverTemplate As DocuSign.ServerTemplate = New DocuSign.ServerTemplate()

    serverTemplate.Sequence = sequence
    serverTemplate.TemplateID = templateID

    Dim serverTemplates(0) As DocuSign.ServerTemplate
    serverTemplates(0) = serverTemplate

    template.ServerTemplates = serverTemplates

    'Inline Template
    Dim inlineTemplate As DocuSign.InlineTemplate = New DocuSign.InlineTemplate()

    inlineTemplate.Sequence = "1"
    inlineTemplate.Envelope = New DocuSign.Envelope()
    inlineTemplate.Envelope.Recipients = signers
    inlineTemplate.Envelope.AccountId = _accountId

    Dim inlineTemplates(0) As DocuSign.InlineTemplate
    inlineTemplates(0) = inlineTemplate

    template.InlineTemplates = inlineTemplates

    'Document.
    template.Document = New DocuSign.Document()
    template.Document.ID = "1"
    template.Document.Name = ""
    template.Document.PDFBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path:=docPath)
    template.Document.FileExtension = "pdf"

    Return template

End Function
```

Comment: Are you positive you have not made ANY changes to your code compared to when it was working?  And what about the document you are using to test, do you get the error for other documents?  What about other document types, such as .rtf .txt for instance?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there were issues with the DocuSign Demo environment (server) recently, according to the DocuSign Trust Center.  This is most likely what was causing your issues.

These issues are currently resolved and your envelopes should be working again now.  For reference, this is the DocuSign Trust Center with monitoring on the DEMO environment:

https://trust.docusign.com/system-status/demo